# Qt: QMediaPlayer.setSource() was blocking the GUI so I moved it to a separate thread; am I doing this right?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

Running this code:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtMultimedia as qtm
from PySide6 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmw
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc

app = qtw.QApplication()
path = "video.mp4"
video_widget = qtmw.QVideoWidget()
video_widget.show()
media_player = qtm.QMediaPlayer()
media_player.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(media_player.play)
media_player.setSource(path)
qtc.QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: media_player.setSource(''))

app.exec()
```

, you will notice that when `media_player.setSource('')` is called after `2000` milliseconds, the GUI becomes unresponsive for a good second or so. And it seems like it is not possible to move only the `setSource()` call to a separate thread, I get a warning saying `QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread` (you can replicate this by replacing `qtc.QTimer...` call with `qtc.QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(lambda: media_player.setSource(''))`). So, after hours of pondering, as a work around, I moved the entire `QMediaPlayer` instance and all objects related to it to a thread of its own and used `QVideoSink`'s `videoFrameChanged` signal to update the video on the video widget:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtMultimedia as qtm
from PySide6 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmw
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc


path = "video.mp4"

class VideoPlayer(qtmw.QVideoWidget):
    _stop_worker_signal = qtc.Signal()
    _initialize_media_player_signal = qtc.Signal()
    _set_media_source_signal = qtc.Signal(str)
    _play_media_signal = qtc.Signal()
    _stop_media_signal = qtc.Signal()
    _pause_media_signal = qtc.Signal()

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker_thread = qtc.QThread()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._worker_thread)
        self._stop_worker_signal.connect(self._worker.stop)
        self._initialize_media_player_signal.connect(self._worker.create_media_player)
        self._worker.video_sink_frame_changed_signal.connect(lambda frame: self.videoSink().setVideoFrame(frame))
        self._set_media_source_signal.connect(self._worker.set_media_source)
        self._stop_media_signal.connect(self._worker.stop_media)
        self._worker_thread.start()
        self._initialize_media_player_signal.emit()
        self._set_media_source_signal.emit(path)
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key.Key_Q:
            self._set_media_source_signal.emit('')

    def closeEvent(self, event: qtc.QEvent):
        loop = qtc.QEventLoop()
        self._worker.stopped_signal.connect(loop.exit)
        self._stop_worker_signal.emit()
        loop.exec()
        self._worker_thread.exit()

class Worker(qtc.QObject):
    video_sink_frame_changed_signal = qtc.Signal(qtm.QVideoFrame)
    stopped_signal = qtc.Signal()

    def create_media_player(self):
        self._audio_output = qtm.QAudioOutput(qtm.QMediaDevices.defaultAudioOutput())
        self._video_sink = qtm.QVideoSink()
        self._video_sink.videoFrameChanged.connect(self.video_sink_frame_changed_signal)
        self._media_player = qtm.QMediaPlayer()
        self._media_player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)
        self._media_player.setVideoSink(self._video_sink)
        self._media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self._media_player.play)

    def set_media_source(self, source: str) -> None:
        self._media_player.setSource(source)

    def stop_media(self) -> None:
        if not self._media_player.playbackState() == qtm.QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.StoppedState:
            self._media_player.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self._media_player.stop()
        self._audio_output.deleteLater()
        self._video_sink.deleteLater()
        self._media_player.deleteLater()
        self.stopped_signal.emit()


app = qtw.QApplication()
vp = VideoPlayer()
app.exec()
```

Now, there's no unresponsiveness in the GUI when `setSource()` is called but, as one can see, it's a pretty convoluted way to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: Shouldn't the [`source`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#source-prop) property type be a QUrl? Even the Qt for Python documentation confirms that (as it should), it seems quite strange that it accepts a simple string.

Comment: @musicamante, the function signature from `help(QMediaPlayer().setSource)` shows `setSource(self, source: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QUrl, str])`. Which is also how I got the idea to use a plain string as opposed to a `QUrl`.

Comment: Seems a bit odd and inconsistent, but whatever. I can actually reproduce the issue, though a bit inconsistently (sometimes it happens almost instantly, other times it takes much more). I'm under the impression that the issue might be related to the reinitialization of the platform player, and if that's the case, I'm afraid that there could be no solution (at least, not right now). You may consider submitting a bugreport.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on linux. Or at least, AFAICS, there's no unexpected behaviour. How do you tell if the GUI is unresponsive for only one second, and why does it matter? Is there some kind of visual indication of the problem?

Comment: @musicamante `QUrl` defines an [assignment operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#operator-eq-1) for `QString`, so strictly speaking any API that takes a url should also take a string. (That's not how things seems to work in PyQt, though - which could be seen as a bug).

Comment: @ekhumoro Right, I see it now. Well, I understand the concept, but doesn't seem consistent. Besides, would it work in C++? About your other comment, I can reproduce the behavior by using a QElapsedTimer started right before `setSource()`, and right after shows an elapsed value up to half a second in some tests, while other times it's just around 10-20ms.

Comment: @musicamante -> "consider submitting a bug report", I see. I'll do just that then.

Comment: @ekhumoro I also am on Linux. I believe Musicamante answered the "how do you know", as for "why does it matter", it should, shouldn't it? No user likes an unresponsive GUI even if just for a second. At least I would expect the GUI to stay responsive while I changed the video being played.

Comment: @Neat I understand your preoccupation, *but*... changing media is not something that happens easily: even with modern computers, accessing a media is not immediate. And *switching* it (even to "no media) isn't either: there is a painful amount of things that happens for that, including interaction with the OS multimedia framework (remember that QtMultimedia does **not** play things on its own). It might seem "easy", but is not: even clearing resources (including audio/video buffers) needs some time. You have to pay for that somewhere: either by "blocking", or by making the system more complex.

Comment: @Neat consider the simple case of threading: you can do some "time-consuming" process in the main thread, which would block the UI completely. It's simple, but it makes the UI unresponsive. You want to keep the UI available in the meantime? Ok, but you need threading, and make things more complex; also, in order to do that, you could even make that process less performant than originally was. Take your case: it works, but it also requires a much more convoluted approach that is more demanding during playback, and that happens **always**. Now, is that less-than-a-second-switch really worth it?

Comment: @musicamante I see. Well, the user still has to wait for the next video to load, all the code in OP does is keep the GUI responsive while the switch happens, as opposed to leaving it unresponsive. Though, I still have to test how it works with successive changes if the user were to do so.

Comment: @musicamante regarding your second comment, you make a valid point. Perhaps I'll think about this if/when the users complaint about it.

Comment: @Neat In my opinion, doing all that just to keep the UI responsive for that short time is counterproductive: 1. as said, you're making the *whole playing process* much less performant in order to just avoid a possibly one-time gap of "unresponsiveness" (users rarely switch media so often); 2. the loading time will probably remain at some level, so that waiting gap will still exist anyway: making the UI responsive won't improve a lot (on the contrary, users seeing the UI responsive might think that there was no effect in their action, and handling user events in the meantime might be risky);

Comment: @Neat 3. using threading to show the video can result in asynchronous playing, especially if the computer is not that performant or many active procesess are running in the meantime, since that would potentially delay the display of images: some people find it annoying having even a 20-30ms audio/video delay. Now, imagine being a user of your program: do you really prefer a media player that is responsive while *still* waiting for the media to play for less than a second, or a program that doesn't eat resources unnecessarily the whole time and play things as smooth as their system can?

Comment: @musicamante I see what you mean. Thank you for the insight, I'll keep it single threaded.

Comment: @Neat Allowing user-interaction whilst the program is in an indeterminate state would be handing them a foot-gun. It's really in the user's best interests that the GUI stays unresponsive during that brief phase whilst the media changes. If the user stops a video, they should expect that many elements of the GUI will become disabled until a new video is started.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact issue, I did research but couldn't find any appealing answer to this.

I studied the code and seems like **.setSource()** does not like being called before the **QMediaPlayer** is stopped completely.

So after some consideration, it turns out the solution is simple:

This actually solved my issue:

```py
import time

#... the code here
def changeSource(source):

    # Stop playing first
    myplayer.stop()
    
    # Here pause a little bit before setSource()
    time.sleep(.01)

    # Now set source
    myplayer.setSource(source)

    # Now you can play
    myplayer.play()
```

Happy coding!